# Golang Random Sha256

Tags: string, random, go, type-conversion, sha256

I am having trouble getting a random sha256 hash using a timestamp seed:

https://play.golang.org/p/2-_VPe3oFr (dont use playground - time always same)

Does anyone understand why it always returns the same result? (non-playground runs)

Comment: Please post your code. (A link to `play.golang.org` is fine, but it's not a substitute for the code itself.)

Comment: Why would you want a "random sha256 hash"? A sha256 hash is not random; it's a deterministic function of its input. If what you need is a random sequence of 256 bits, why should sha256 be involved?

Answer (score 13):

Because you do this:

```
timestamp := time.Now().Unix()
log.Print(fmt.Sprintf("%x", sha256.Sum256([]byte(string(timestamp))))[:45])
```

You print the hex form of the SHA-256 digest of the data:

```
[]byte(string(timestamp))
```

What is it exactly?

`timestamp` is of type `int64`, [converting it to string is](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type):

> Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer. Values outside the range of valid Unicode code points are converted to "\uFFFD".

But its value is not a valid unicode code point so it will always be `"\uFFFD"` which is `efbfbd` (UTF-8 encoded), and your code always prints the SHA-256 of the data `[]byte{0xef, 0xbf, 0xbd}` which is (or rather its first 45 hex digits because you slice the result):

```
83d544ccc223c057d2bf80d3f2a32982c32c3c0db8e26
```

I guess you wanted to generate some random bytes and calculate the SHA-256 of that, something like this:

```
data := make([]byte, 10)
for i := range data {
    data[i] = byte(rand.Intn(256))
}
fmt.Printf("%x", sha256.Sum256(data))
```

Note that if you'd use the [`crypto/rand`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/) package instead of `math/rand`, you could fill a slice of bytes with random values using the [`rand.Read()`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/#Read) function, and you don't even have to set seed (and so you don't even need the `time` package):

```
data := make([]byte, 10)
if _, err := rand.Read(data); err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("%x", sha256.Sum256(data))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This:

```
string(timestamp)
```

does not do what you think it does, see [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type). Long story short, the timestamp is not a valid unicode code point, so the result is always "\uFFFD".